# Android R.raw.class.getFields() returns no fields on release

Tags: java, android, reflection, android-resources

I have following code (located in static method in public class, called on app start from `MainActivity.onPostCreate`):

```
Field[] fields = R.raw.class.getFields();
StringBuilder allFields = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    Field field = fields[i];
    allFields.append(field.getName() + " - " + field.getModifiers());
}
```

(this code is part of functionality for checking if resources are intact)

I had this mechanism for some time, but now (after updating code to new API-Level 30) it stopped working. When I run application from Android Studio then fields are found and I can list them.

But when I build app and run `.apk` it on the **same device** then fields array is empty. App works normally and all resources are available for normal usage.

I tried unpacking `.apk` file and I found expected keys in `apk/res/values/public.xml`. I also inspected project and fixed all errors.

Was there some change in privacy for this fields (in API 29 or 30)? Why I cannot access this data?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to localize and fix the problem. It was related to changes made in gradle process. One of the version changed default handling of `android.R` class in pro-guard configuration.

To go back to earlier configuration you can add the following to your pro-guard properties file:

```
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}
```